# Cannot set property start of #<EventApi> which has only a getter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar

I have the following error on the console:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot set property start of #<EventApi> which has only a getter"
TypeError: Cannot set property start of #<EventApi> which has only a getter
```

I have the following code:

```
 function generateRecurrenceArray(event, dateStart, dateEnd) {
  let arr = []
  let intervalWeek = [ 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70 ]
  let repeatEnd = new Date(event.extendedProps.repeat_ends_at)
  let repeatInterval = event.extendedProps.repeat_interval
 
  if(event.extendedProps.repeat_ends == 'on_date') {
    if(repeatEnd >= dateEnd) {
      repeatEnd = dateEnd;
    }
  } else {
    repeatEnd = dateEnd;
  }

  if(event.start <= dateStart) {
    event.start = dateStart;
  }
  
  while (event.start <= repeatEnd) {    
    event.start = new Date(event.start.setDate(event.start.getDate() + intervalWeek[repeatInterval - 1]))
    event.end = new Date(event.end.setDate(event.end.getDate() + intervalWeek[repeatInterval - 1]))
    
    let event2 = _.cloneDeep(event);
    arr.push(event2);
  }

  return arr;
}
```

I am using FullCalendar on v5 in my project. The objective is: I search for the event registered on the back-end, and the event that is recurring, from this function generates the array of corresponding events. For example, if the registered event is repeated every Wednesday from 8:00 am until 5:00 pm on the Thursday, it must be repeated this way every week.

This is the event object:
[image]

I have everything ok, but the problem that occurs to me is in the loop.

If anyone can help me, I appreciate it.

Comment: `event.start = ..` is the line that fails. `start` has been defined as as a getter (without a setter), apparently. This results in an runtime error (as opposed to silently doing nothing). Use new variables, perhaps.

Comment: You cannot mutate the properties directly. Probably something like `event.setStart(...)` will work.

Comment: It looks like you're already setting `event.start` with `event.start.setDate()`, so `event.start = /*...*/` is unnecessary.